# Stripe payment to a customer with customer_id(strip_id)

Tags: stripe-payments, strip

I have created an donation app for user.

1. Added a user and created customer with user login credentials using devise and stripe.
2. Then Created a donation page where anyone can come and donate money without registering.

Below is the UI.

[image: Donation_list]

Now I want to pay the customer which is registered with **Bio:hello** with his customer_ID by below code.

```
token = params[:stripeToken]

  Stripe::Charge.create(
    customer: @user.stripe_id,
    source: token,
    amount:   2000,
    currency: 'usd',
    description: 'Example charge'
  )



But its throwing error. Stripe::InvalidRequestError: Customer cus_** does not have a linked source with ID tok_**.
```

**PLease help me how to donate some amount without registering my account to this user.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach/save the `Token` to the `Customer` first [0].

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards#saving-credit-card-details-for-later

Comment: As per your answer we are just creating the customer and charging from his card. But how this money will transfer to others registered card.

My Requirement is suppose you are the user with bio: hello and you already added your customer detail and created card detail too.
Now When I will click donate donate button, UI should popup showing card details and money,
Which will further transfer to your card.

Comment: Sounds like you're walking about Payouts to a connected account (the "others" in your description). I'd suggest contacting [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/contact) for suggestions on how to model your entire business flow.